# How to use std::ifstream to read in a binary file with a wide string path

Tags: c++, fstream

I am reading a binary file as:

```
const size_t stBuffer = 256;
char buffer[stBuffer];
std::wstring wPath(L"blah");
std::wifstream ifs(wPath.c_str(), std::wifstream::in | std::wifstream::binary)
while (ifs.good())
{
  ifs.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  ...
}
```

But I am realizing this is not a true binary read. The ifstream actually reads a byte and converts it to a wide char. So if the binary file has the content `0x112233...ff`, I actually read `0x110022003300...ff00`.

This doesn't make much sense to me: first, I only need to use a wide fstream because the file name is non Latin. Second, if I say the fstream is binary, why does `read` read wide chars? The code below does what I want. Is there a way to achieve that using std fstreams?

```
FILE* ifs = _wfopen(L"blah", L"rb");
while (!feof(ifs))
{
  size_t numBytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), ifs);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The current C++ standard doesn't provide wide char paths. Even the wchar_t version receives a regular const char* filename. You already used a compiler extension, so continue using this extension with a normal ifstream:

```
std::wstring wPath(L"blah");
std::ifstream ifs(wPath.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary)
```

**EDIT:** consider [using utf-8 strings](http://utf8everywhere.org) instead of wide strings and use [Boost.Nowide](http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/) (not yet in boost) to open files.

**EDIT:** Boost.Nowide was accepted in boost. Also Windows 10 [added support for UTF-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) in its narrow-string API, which can be enabled through a manifest. This makes all the wide-char interfaces pretty much unportable and redundant.

Comment: Does that work?  `std::wstring::c_str()` returns `const wchar_t *` and `std::ifstream`'s constructor takes `const char *`.  That's why rturrado was using the w versions.  (I hate the iostreams assumption that bytes are possibly-signed chars.)

Comment: @Adrian: the w version constructor takes `const char *` **too** (see the standacd). The wchar_t versian **is a compiler extension**, it works on Microsoft C++ compiler, which is probably what the OP uses. My code will work fine on his implementation because he **ALREADY uses this extension**. So please, don't downvote if you didn't actually verified or understood what I say, you may be wrong.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio for Windows and intel compiler for Linux. Your solution worked fine in Windows. I haven't tried it yet on Linux. It's quite an elegant solution. I'd prefer not to rely on compiler extensions though. Do you think you can do this sticking to the standard, maybe specifying the charset as a templated parameter to ifstream?

Comment: UTF-8 is better under Linux, but I don't think that works with MS-Windows, however... that would be viewed as the current locale and not UTF-8. From your link to a document explaining UTF-8: "[...] Furthermore, since UTF-8 cannot be set as the encoding for narrow string WinAPI [...]" -- in other words you pretty much need to have a different call for each platform, right? Or use wchar_t functions on either platforms.

Comment: @ybungalobill: yes, that document about UTF-8 is really good. I wish MS-Windows chose UTF-8 too, but they defined that stupid UNICODE macro and most people do not even know that most of the functions that support a string have two versions (the A and W...) Anyway, I agree. One "easy" way is to put all the system specific functions in one file or at least one directory (depending on the size of your project) and then call those functions instead of directly the system functions. That way you change those 100 calls to these overrides and it becomes 1 call per OS specific function maybe 10 total.

Comment: This is bad code. `.c_str()` here gives a wchar_t*.

Comment: @Andrew Did you take the time to read previous comments? Yes, it gives `wchar_t*`. MSVC has an `ifstream` constructor that receives a `wchar_t*`. When this answer was written you didn't have another way of doing this. This doesn't make this code 'bad'.

Comment: @YakovGalka On Linux at least, it appears to want `char*` only (even `std::wifstream`). Other answers have said c++ only supports regular string paths.

Comment: @Andrew The answer says that it is a non-standard extension; OP targets windows, and uses that exact extension **already**. The answer is on-point to what OP asks. If you have questions about linux you should ask a different question.