# How can I use a wregex in C++11?

Tags: regex, visual-c++, c++11

I tried using a normal regex and everything was fine, The time I switched to a wregex for searching and tokenizing among Unicode characters, it failed and I can't understand why.
Can someone please point out what I am missing here?

```
map<string, int> container;
wifstream file("ftest.txt"); 
wregex reg(_T("\\w+"));
wstring s=_T("");
while (file.good())
{
    file>>s;
    for ( wsregex_iterator it (s.cbegin(), s.cend(), reg),it_end; it != it_end; ++it)
    {
        container[(*it)[0]]++ ;
    }

}
```

The contents of my file are in Farsi, such as :

```
بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم 
تست یک تست 2 . 2357 نفر آمار تست اولیه هرچی!!
```

These are the errors it generated :

> error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'const std::sub_match<_BidIt>' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)
>
> IntelliSense: no operator "[]" matches these operands operand types
>   are: std::map,
>   std::allocator>> [ const
>   std::sub_match>>> ]

Comment: How did it fail? Can you give an example line from your non-english file and the ouput that you expect?

Comment: it stopped at compile time! i add the error to the question in a few seconds

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using? Under which platform?

Comment: Visual C++2012 UpdatePack3

Comment: what happens if you make the declaration of s a wide string instead?

Comment: If i do wstring str =_T(" "); then i will have a problem here: 
file>>s; , it says there is no overload for wstring for >> operator!!

Comment: But I think that s.begin() and s.end() are returning the wrong iterator types.

Comment: i changed them to s.cbegin() and s.cend() still they generate that error!!

Comment: I meant that they were iterators to string instead of wstring. They must not be constant.

Comment: This is how you use wstring with ifstream http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382451/how-to-use-stdifstream-to-read-in-a-binary-file-with-a-wide-string-path

Comment: Thanks, i changed ifstream to wifstream and the inserssion operator seems to like wstring now :), now the only problem i have is the map! i'll update the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

s.begin() and s.end() should return wstring iterators (make s a wstring).

This is how you use wstring with ifstream 
[How to use std::ifstream to read in a binary file with a wide string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382451/how-to-use-stdifstream-to-read-in-a-binary-file-with-a-wide-string-path)

The map should be `map<wstring, int>` too.

Comment: Thanks, but i get an error when trying to use cout with my maps!?
cout<<item.first;
how to get around this?

Comment: you can use the ifstream trick, but in reverse. Use cout << my_wstring.c_str() << endl;

Comment: or yet better use std::wcout :)