# C++ - I see incorrect value in debugger (MS VS 2015)

Tags: c++, fstream

First time I use a C++ file streams. And I have a problem.
(Windows 8.1 x64, MS VS 2015, but mscrt v.120 (from MS VS 2013) x64)

After line `fin >> m`, `m` is equal to `0xccccccccccc`, but must be equal to `570`.

<s>Function `fscanf` works fine and returns `m=570`.
 Function `std::getline (fin, line)` also returns `line="570"`.</s>

Doubles, which follow the first int, will be read fine.

**edit:** I don't try to check the value of variable by printf.

<s>Why doesn't the input operator work as expected?
 What don't I understand?</s>

```
  #include <string>
  #include <fstream>
  #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
  #define _UNICODE
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <tchar.h>

  typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

  size_t  m;
  tstring filename;
  // --------------------------------
  std::ifstream  fin (filename, std::ios_base::in);
  if ( fin.is_open () )
  {
    if ( fin >> m )  // !!!
    { angles.resize (m); }
    else
    { throw std::exception ("ifstream error"); }

    double angle = 0.;
    while ( fin >> angle )
    { angles.push_back (angle); }

    double angle = 0.;
    while ( fin >> angle )
    { angles.push_back (angle); }
    // --------------------------------
    size_t m = angles.size (); / <--- HERE 
    //  is the DEFINITION of the new variable with the same name.
    //  It is created on a stack, so before it's been initialized,
    //  it has the value = 0xcccccccc.
    frames.resize (m);
    // --------------------------------
    for ( size_t i = 1U; i < m; ++i )
    { frames[i] = i; }
    // --------------------------------
  }
  else
  { throw std::exception ("ifstream: input error."); }
}
```

The text file does not consist of a BOM or something...
Here it's the binary view:

[image: Binary view of input data]

Comment: Here are some thing to try: 1) replace `fin` with `cin` and run.  2) Assign `m` a default value and run. 3) Change the type of `m` to `unsigned int` or `uint32_t`.  There may be an issue reading the file.

Comment: In DEBUG version with all types and fin and cin this strange thing is repeated. In RELEASE all is OK. But I understand, that it is a strange behavior of the MS VS debugger. Now I changed the name to `mii` and now I see `570`.

Comment: Note that `oxcccccccc` indicates [uninitialized stack memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values), so `m` never gets written to. But it's hard to tell what's going wrong in your case without a [mcve].

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, Thank you very much for your peaces of advice.

Comment: @mindriot, I have already understood and posted the answer.

Answer (score -2):

When opening a file with `std::ifstream`, the file name parameter needs to be a C string of type `const char*`.

I would also suggest that you would use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>.c_str()` or just the regular `std::string.c_str()`.

Comment: Maybe, because of it is C++11- there is a new constructor of `std::ifstream` that takes a `std::wstring`.

Comment: In C++11, `std::ifstream` has a [constructor taking a `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream), but not `std::wstring`. See also [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382451/how-to-use-stdifstream-to-read-in-a-binary-file-with-a-wide-string-path).

Comment: @mindriot, MS VS compiler extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382451/how-to-use-stdifstream-to-read-in-a-binary-file-with-a-wide-string-path#comment6087179_5382504

Answer (score -3):

As I have incorrectly written in a comment: <strike>The problem in internal variables of MS VS Debugger</strike>. As expected it is my fault.

The incorrect value of variable in the debugger I can see only in DEBUG version. 
In RELEASE, the variable has the right value in the debugger.

So, the solution is to rename a variable to see in debugger the correct value.

---

All code of a function:

```
{
  std::ifstream  fin (filename, std::ios_base::in);
  // --------------------------------
  if ( fin.is_open () )
  {
    size_t  m;
    if ( fin >> m ) // << 0xccccccccc
    { angles.reserve (m); }
    else
    { throw std::exception ("ifstream: input error."); }

    double angle = 0.;
    while ( fin >> angle )
    { angles.push_back (angle); }
    // --------------------------------
    size_t m = angles.size (); // <--- HERE 
    //  is the DEFINITION of the new variable with the same name.
    //  It is created on a stack, so before it's been initialized,
    //  it has the value = 0xcccccccc. That I can see.
    frames.resize (m);
    // --------------------------------
    for ( size_t i = 1U; i < m; ++i )
    { frames[i] = i; }
    // --------------------------------
  }
  else
  { throw std::exception ("ifstream: input error."); }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this is really the problem. You can name your variables anything you like, neither the VS compiler nor the debugger care. Something else is wrong here. You're probably running into Undefined Behaviour because of something else in your code that you're not showing us.

Comment: @mindriot, Thank you, I understand where I was wrong. Answer corrected.

Answer (score -6):

I would suggest you to change the data type of the m variable into int, because the function size() returns an integer as far as I know and store the number in the variable m. Then create a variable test with data type size_t with the following syntax: size_t test = m. If it is a bug of the debugger, try to use sizeof() instead of size_t data type. This means that the previous could be wrote like: sizeof(m) and store it in a variable. I wish I helped you.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain the difference in input and output that the OP is experiencing.

Comment: Yes. Well, Idon't know the problem and I just suggested a different and better header file. I think that saying that I can help him interact better with files.

Comment: `cstdio` is a C header containing old C functions. I could understand if someone has reasons to use them instead of the C++ alternative (`fstream`) but you do not mention a single good reason

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis The OP is looking for a working C++ solution, not a C solution.

Comment: _"Well, Idon't know the problem and I just suggested..."_ Didn't we agree a few days ago that you wouldn't do this any more?